# Flutter reset all provider states after sign out

Tags: flutter

Whenever I sign out of my app, it seems to not clear all provider states and when I log in to another user my app crashes. Is there way to reset everything to default when performing logout action?

Comment: could you provide some code?

Comment: Check flutter phoenix to reset your app. 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the scope of your provided objects. If you provide them at top level, the instances will not be disposed and live on.

Possible solutions could be:

1. Provide your state further down in the widget tree.
2. Observe a logout event in your state and perform reset of state automatically. There are multiple ways to do this, e.g. use a ProxyProvider.

```dart
ProxyProvider<Session, SomeStateClass>(
  create: (_) => SomeStateClass(),
  update: (_, session, instanceOfStateClass) {
   return instanceOfStateClass..reinitialize(session);
}),
```

In the example above, the update method gets called, when Session notifies about changes.

Comment: The thing is I am accessing the states like this for e.g `context.watch<Profile>().getName`
or `Provider.of<Profile>(context, listen: false).getName` in the code, is my approach bad?

Comment: No, but of course, if you sign out of the application, you need to somehow update the state of `Profile`, by setting the new user after he signs in, for example.

Comment: Im fairly new to flutter, would you recommend riverpod over provider, or maybe anything else?

Comment: We used Provider in the past, but we now use BLoC in every project: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc